# Change 'FROM' field in reply event for a shared mailbox

Tags: vba, email, outlook

**Description of the problem:**

I have to change the sender ('from' field ) of a message. I added two shared mailbox accounts and while I'm clicking reply on the item, which belongs to one of them, I want to send this reply message from the other shared mailbox.

**My (not working) solution:**

I used event _Reply. I'm changing the property .SentOnBehalfOfName, assigning the email address of the second shared mailbox. The 'from' field in the message editor changes to the proper address, but after sending the message the person who received it sees that I sent it from the first email address and in my "sent items" folder the message appears as sent on behalf of "second email address".

**My code (located in thisOutlookSession):**

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Public strSender1 As String 'name of shered mailbox which is owner of the mail
Public strSender2 As String 'address of shered mailbox

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
   bDiscardEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()
   On Error Resume Next
   Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.Item(1)
End Sub

Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    strSender1 = "Name of mailbox1"
    strSender2 = "mailbox2@dsg.dk"
    If Response.Class = olMail Then
        If Response.Sender Is Nothing Then
             'MsgBox "There's no sender for the current email", vbInformation
             Exit Sub
        End If
        If Response.Sender = strSender1 Then
            MsgBox "Field 'From' has been changed to " + strSender2
            Response.SentOnBehalfOfName = strSender2
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox Response.SentOnBehalfOfName
    'Set oItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes I think you need SendUsingAccount

```
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    strSender1 = "Name of mailbox1"

    If Response.Class = olMail Then

        If oItem.AutoForwarded = True Then

            If oItem.Sender = strSender1 Then

                ' oItem was autoforwarded from
                '  strSender1 - name of shared mailbox which is owner of the mail
                Response.SendUsingAccount = Session.Accounts.Item(1)
                MsgBox "Field 'From' has been changed to " + strSender1

            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

To determine the account number:

```
Private Sub AccountNames()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Session.Accounts.Count
        Debug.Print " Account " & i & " DisplayName....: " & _
          Session.Accounts.Item(i).DisplayName
        Debug.Print
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I solved the problem by different way, but I will look closer to your solution when I will have some free time. I think I tried something like that with no succeeds...

Comment: @BłażejŁaszewski do you mind sharing how you fixed it? We're experiencing the same problem.